# problem with axis client stub timeout

Tags: java, web-services

I am writing an application which uses web services to connect a remote server.I have written a method to ping function to determine if the server is online or not(i.e. its providing the web services which can be accessed using host:port).I am executing a simple web service with a 2 sec timeout(available as an option in stub class before I make the call).Ideally the call should return within 2 seconds allowing me to ascertain whether the server is up or down.However in certain cases it takes far longer than 2 seconds.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?Is there a way to ensure that the timeout value is honored ?

Thanks,
Fell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the default http sender, switch to commons http client based sender. Details are here - http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/AxisCommonsHTTP - Same page has details on how to set various kinds of timeouts as well.

Comment: Above solution is not working. Using Axis 1.4 & Java 1.7. In-fact, not a single approach is working for Axis read time out.. surprise ! Tried all options mentioned in below link - http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/AxisCommonsHTTP
 --/-- 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/544075/Web-Services/java/set-timeout-Axis-client
 --/--
https://samaxes.com/2009/04/axis-14-read-timed-out-and-http-11/

Answer (score 3):

In Axis client stubs, there is an option for you to set the timeout. You can also use it. Note that the time-out is measured in milliseconds. [check here](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/client/Stub.html#setTimeout%28int%29)

And if it is Axis2, you can use like this:

```
Stub s = new Stub();
ServiceClient sc = s.getServiceClient();
Options o = sc.getOptions();
o.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(2000); //2 seconds
sc.setOptions(o);
s.setServiceClient(sc);
```

You can make your calls after setting the above stuff.

Answer (score 0):

With axis 1.4 found that actual timeout set from Stub::setTimeout is then appear in SocketFactoryFactory::getFactory, but if the factory for protocol is found in cache, new timeout value is ignored.

Cleaning the cache seems to fix the issue

```
stub.setTimeout(10000);
Map factories = (Map) FieldUtils.readDeclaredStaticField(SocketFactoryFactory.class, "factories", true);
factories.clear();
```