# Inject client options in Axis 2 stubs using Spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-axis

I have used `wsdl2java` ant task to create several proxies for different web services using Axis2. Since some of these take considerable time to complete, I need to set timeout accordingly.

As of [problem with axis client stub timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336989/problem-with-axis-client-stub-timeout) I can programmatically set timeout using `ServiceClient` class. I want to efficiently set timeout for any service client in my project. Currently I had to create a factory bean for a specific service and manually set timeout there:

Context:

```
<bean id="xmlValidatorServiceFactory" class="it.csttech.edwin.consumercredit.business.factory.XmlValidatorStubFactory">
        <property name="xmlValidatorUrl" value="${validator.url}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="xmlValidatorWebService" class="it.csttech.edwin.services.axis2.XmlValidatorStub" factory-bean="xmlValidatorServiceFactory" factory-method="create">
    </bean>
```

Factory:

```
public XmlValidatorStub create() throws Exception
{
    XmlValidatorStub ret = new XmlValidatorStub();
    ret._getServiceClient()
            .getOptions()
            .setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(1000000);

    return ret;
}
```

I want to ask if such option can be set efficiently using Spring for any web service stub defined as bean